# mitmproxy: TlsException, handshake error, unsupported protocol

Tags: ssl, curl, mitmproxy

I'm trying to use mitmproxy to talk to a very old server.

```bash
$ mitmproxy --version
Mitmproxy: 6.0.2
Python:    3.10.12
OpenSSL:   OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
Platform:  Linux-6.5.0-14-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
```

I can connect to the server like this (`ssh -L ...` in the background):

`curl --tls-max 1.1 --ciphers DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0 -v -k https://localhost:4433`

But I can't get my browser to view that (Chrome and FF just refuse to negotiate with the server).

I thought I could use mitmproxy to 'upgrade' the security on the fly, but apparently not...

`mitmweb --ssl-insecure` then

`curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 -k https://localhost:4433`

gives:

```html
<html>
            <head>
                <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
            <p>TlsProtocolException(&#x27;Cannot establish TLS with localhost:4433 (sni: localhost): TlsException(&quot;SSL handshake error: Error([(\&#x27;SSL routines\&#x27;, \&#x27;\&#x27;, \&#x27;unsupported protocol\&#x27;)])&quot;)&#x27;)</p>
            </body>
        </html>
```

### EDIT

Setting OPENSSL_CONF like this worked finally (debugged using the same config with curl):

```
openssl_conf = default_conf

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect
  
[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0
```

then calling `OPENSSL_CONF=$PWD/ssl.conf mitmproxy`

Comment: Chrome and FF require at least TLS 1.2. `ssl_insecure` option of mitmproxy is only about certificate validation which is irrelvant here, try `tls_version_client_min` instead (which defaults to TLS 1.2).

Comment: `mitmproxy: error: unrecognized arguments: --tls-version-client-min`

Comment: Also tried version 10.2.2. BTW, do you do the stormcast? Big fan :-)

Comment: `mitmproxy --set tls_version_client_min=TLS1`

Comment: Thanks, I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. I see that option in the mitmweb options now, and I've tried various settings of tls_version_client_min and tls_version_server_min... while `curl --tls-max 1.1 --ciphers DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0 -v -k  https://localhost:4433/start.html` works fine, no version of `curl --proxy localhost:8080 ... https://localhost:4433/start.html` works.